# ansible iterate with loop over collection

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

When executing `ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local main.yml` the output is

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=users) => {
    "item": "users",
    "msg": "use
```

But I rather would like to iterate over the elements. How can this be achieved?

Here my minimal example:

main.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug: msg={{ item }}
      #include_vars: users.yml
      with_items: users
```

users.yml

```
---
users:
  - username: test_user
    password: test_user
    sn: User
    uid: 50001
    gid: 100
  - username: test_user1
    password: test_user
    cn: Test User1
    sn: User1
    uid: 50002
    gid: 100

user_groups:
  - cn: access1
    gid: 100001
    users:
      - test_user1
```

Comment: There is a [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html) about loops in ansible.

Comment: Indeed I already followed that documentation but so far had no success. When writing `with_items: "{{ users }}"` I only see an error of `with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct syntax:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_vars: users.yml
    - debug: msg={{ item }}
      with_items: "{{ users }}"
```